# Kibana - can't create index pattern after deleting all

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

[image]I deleted all my index patterns (I still have few indexes in elasticsearch, also visible from management in kibana). Right now I wanted to create new (first) index pattern, but there is message:

> No default index pattern. You must select or create one to continue.

but I can't create one because of screen is only showing message above and:

> Checking for Elasticsearch data

so basically, I need to have default index pattern to create one, but I can't assign any index to be default, because I don't have any index pattern :(

I am on Windows and I am using version 6.5.4 of Kibana and Elasticsearch.

Do you have any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Try using *. as pattern

Comment: menu for creating is not displaying, i cant enter anything, because of error:
"No default index pattern. You must select or create one to continue."

Comment: You can select any  index using *. No need to create new one.

Comment: But as I said, I cant select anything, there is no field to enter patern

Comment: What do you get when running `GET _cat/indices` in Dev Tools?

Comment: green  open .kibana_1                   xrxo1dVLS0uq8YWc4vXuag 1 0     3 0 11.9kb 11.9kb
yellow open metricbeat-6.5.4-2019.01.24 O18QjI8-Rue4BZAT1aEPew 1 1 53460 0  8.7mb  8.7mb